# DataFormWebPart filter toolbar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, dataformwebpart

I've lost the toolbar on my DataFormWebPart that has the dropdown boxes that apply a filter to the data - but I can't see a Filter checkbox in the Properties dialog.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I should never have had it in the first place, it's not normally available when binding a DataFormWebPart to a database datasource. By some odd combination of circumstances Sharepoint Designer enabled it for me for just long enough to tease me into thinking it would work.